# How to compile SASS to CSS

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass, angular-cli

I recently started looking to Angular 4. I have created my project using Angular CLI. I was wondering how do we compile an existing `style.sass` to `style.css` since the CLI uses `webpack` as a default.

In my `angular-cli.json`, I have mentioned `default styles: sass`. Not sure where to go from here. What should I do next? I know webpack has something called as `loaders`which can be used to compile things like `sass`. But not sure how to implement in Angular 4 CLI project.

Comment: Apparently angular.json `styles` allows you to [pass json objects instead of strings](https://www.bytelimes.com/how-to-split-external-styles-into-named-bundles-in-angular/#using-object-notation) too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular-cli takes care of that for you.

Whenever you create a new component, it will create a corresponding component.scss file for you.

What you can do, if you had existing components before setting defaults to scss, is make that modification:

1. Rename the `[componentName].component.css file` to  `[componentName].component.scss`
2. Modify the `[componentName].component.ts` file to replace the value of **styleUrls** to use the scss file instead of the css file
3. Rename your global `styles.css` file to `styles.scss`
4. In the **styles** property of your `.angular-cli.json file`, replace `styles.css` with `styles.scss`

Now, just write sass in the scss files, and they'll be automatically compiled to css by angular-cli

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to start using Sass

1. APPLICATIONS
2. COMMAND LINE

All of the documentation of command line is found in this link below [Also find the APPLICATIONS list]

https://sass-lang.com/install

Try to do yourself. If any problem faces not to hesitate just comment in the box below.

Answer (score 0):

Use Compass It's Best compiler for SASS. [Link for compass Installation](http://compass-style.org/install/)